# jQuery dynamically load image not working showing multipule images how to I replace the src= and not append to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Okay so I have the little function below on my html page that receives data from another script using socket.io to update the url.

The problems is the image can change up to 10 times during the user is using my page.

If I am loading one image, it works, but multiple images don't work, as it appends the next picture to the `src=`.

And not replace it so I end up with multiple images in my div.

How do I changed it so it replace the `src=` and not append to it?

The `src=` is originally empty

Here's my jQuery script:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

function hellou(url){

var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;

var src = document.getElementById("cpt_img");
    src.appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

Can someone show me an example to fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manedeepak08/NHBKR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery>>

```
function hellou(url){

$("#cpt_img").attr("src",url);

}
```

can I have your HTML .. so that I can give you more specific answer

Comment: that should be working. if not - try prop("src", url) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `id` attribute to detect if the image was previously appended or not

```
function hellou(url){
  var img, src;

  if (!document.getElementById('hellou-img')) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = url;
    img.id ='hellou-img';

    src = document.getElementById("cpt_img");
    src.appendChild(img);
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('hellou-img').src = url;
  }
}
```

When you call this function for the first time, the element whose id is `hellou-img` doesn't exist, so it is created and appended. From the second function call, since the element already exists, only its source will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function hellou(url){
    $("img#cpt_img").attr("src", url);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lil bit of jquery should help you do this eaisly

```
$("#image-selector").attr("src", "<url>");
```

Check this fiddle to understand this better : http://jsfiddle.net/U2MVD/

Html:

```
<img id="someImage" src="" />
```

Jquery

```
$("#someImage").attr("src", "smile1.png");

setTimeout(function(){
    $("#someImage").attr("src", "smile2.png");
}, 3000);
```